# what if i add same css file twice in my asp.net application

Tags: asp.net, css, optimization, master-pages

I am developing an ASP.NET application , in which my master page has one css file named "styles/xyz.css" 
now my one other aspx file is aslo adding the same css file "styles/xyz.css" which is using the master page
now my question is how this two same css file will be treated ?
the thing i wanted to know here is "how asp.net engine ( or css rendering engine ) will treat this two file ? "
 will it overwrite the previous css with the new one ? or
 it will load both the file in the memory ?
 or 
it will combine both the css file in one ?

as such there is no referencing error or conflict in my application but i would like to know about the efficiency and memory optimization ..

Comment: Why not try out - does it turn up as one or two links in the browser?

Comment: if you are using a masterpage, why does your child page include stylesheets? Only your masterpage should have a head section.

Comment: @skyfoot, unless you have a content section in your head section.  I do this all the time to dynamically include js files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it will not combine it, it will load it twice.

first it will load the css from the child page, then load it again from the masterpage.

Answer (score 2):

Whichever one is referenced closer to the body tag (or content in question) will take priority when it comes to overriding similiar classes and IDs.